# How to pass "self" or Page.id to a custom admin Panel in the Wagtail CMS?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

More generally speaking I want add a custom admin `Panel` to list some related content. To lookup this related content I need to pass the current instance of the model or at least its ID to this panel. How can I do that within these lists in which these admin panels are noted?

Here is my specific example of an `ArtistPage`. In the editor I would like to add a panel to list `WorkPages` that are related to this `ArtistPage`:

```py
from wagtail.models import Page

class ArtistPage(Page):
# ...
content_panels = [
        # ...
        ListWorksPanel(artist=self),  # This doesn’t work
    ]
```

The panel itself is defined like that, mostly copied from the `HelpPanel`:

```py
from wagtail.admin.panels import Panel

class ListWorksPanel(Panel):
    def __init__(self, artist="", template="admin/list_works_panel.html", **kwargs,):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.artist = artist
        self.template = template

    def clone_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().clone_kwargs()
        del kwargs["help_text"]
        kwargs.update(
            artist=self.artist,
            template=self.template,
        )
        return kwargs

    class BoundPanel(Panel.BoundPanel):
        def __init__(self, panel, instance, request, form):
            super().__init__(panel, instance, request, form)
            self.template_name = self.panel.template
            self.artist = self.panel.artist
```

This is more a general Python question, I think. I know how to pass "self" in functions. **But how does that work here with this class as element of a list?** I reckon that the `__init__()` method of the `ArtistPage` is the way to go, but I cannot figure out how exactly.

**What is the pythonic way of passing "self" to another class?**

### Update (Solution):

Following @gasman’s aswer, I just added the `get_context_data` method to the `BoundPanel` class. The works are accessible in the template of the panel now!

```py
class ListWorksPanel(Panel):
    def __init__(self, artist="", template="admin/list_works_panel.html", **kwargs,):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.artist = artist
        self.template = template

    def clone_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().clone_kwargs()
        del kwargs["help_text"]
        kwargs.update(
            artist=self.artist,
            template=self.template,
        )
        return kwargs

    class BoundPanel(Panel.BoundPanel):
        def __init__(self, panel, instance, request, form):
            super().__init__(panel, instance, request, form)
            self.template_name = self.panel.template
            self.artist = self.panel.artist
            
        def get_context_data(self, parent_context):
            context = super().get_context_data(parent_context)
            context['works'] = self.instance.works.all()  # exactly what I needed
            return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArtistPage instance is passed to `BoundPanel.__init__` as the keyword argument `instance`. All code that deals with an individual ArtistPage needs to be written inside the `BoundPanel` class.

When you write `ListWorksPanel()` as part of a `content_panels` definition, you're creating a `ListWorksPanel` instance that then becomes part of the definition of the ArtistPage *class*. At this point in the code, no actual instance of ArtistPage exists, so there's no `self` to refer to. Effectively, there's a single `ListWorksPanel` object shared by all ArtistPage instances that will ever be created.

When the time comes to render the edit form for an individual page, Wagtail calls `get_bound_panel` on the ListWorksPanel object, passing the page instance along with the form and request objects. ([The full process is explained here](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/forms.html#panels).) This returns an instance of BoundPanel, which is a [template component](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/template_components.html) that performs the final rendering. In this case, you probably want to define a [get_context_data](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/template_components.html#passing-context-to-the-template) method on BoundPanel that does something like `context['works'] = self.instance.works.all()` - this will then make the variable `works` available on the template.

Comment: Thanks @gasman! This solved it for me. I will update my question with your code.